# Show Msgbox if false then exit sub

Tags: excel, vba

I have macros that will let me pick the data file I want first, then proceed to the following steps. But if I were to change my mind and cancel it halfway (before selecting files), then a message box will pop out stating that "You've cancelled the process" and exit the sub.

The problem is that my macros instantly exit sub, even if I pressed on an input data. What is wrong with my macros that is causing them to do this?

```
Sub trial2()

Dim wb As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook, wb3 As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Dim fn As String

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

'this is for the excel to add one more worksheet for the raw data
Set ws = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Worksheets.Count))

Dim ret As Variant
'this whole part is for importing the raw data files into excel
ret = Application.GetOpenFilename("Lkl Files (*.lkl), *.lkl")
If ret <> False Then
Else
MsgBox "You've canceled the process"
With ActiveWorkbook
.Worksheets(.Worksheets.Count).Delete
End With
Exit Sub

With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
"TEXT;" & ret, Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
.Name = ret
.FieldNames = True
.RowNumbers = False
.FillAdjacentFormulas = False
.PreserveFormatting = True
.RefreshOnFileOpen = False
.RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
.SavePassword = False
.SaveData = True
.AdjustColumnWidth = True
.RefreshPeriod = 0
.TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
.TextFilePlatform = 65001
.TextFileStartRow = 1
.TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
.TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
.TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
.TextFileTabDelimiter = True
.TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
.TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
.TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
.TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
.TextFileDecimalSeparator = ","
.TextFileThousandsSeparator = "."
.TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

End With
End If


Sheets(2).Activate

'this is to search for the next empty cell and put the date
Dim FirstCell As String
Dim i As Integer
FirstCell = "C19"
Range(FirstCell).Select
Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""
If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then
Exit Do
Else
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
End If
Loop
ActiveCell = datepart(ret)

'this is to filter the raw data into the desired value
ws.Activate
ws.AutoFilterMode = False

'change the value of Criteria1 between "" into the desired value for filtering
ws.Range("$A$9:$P$417").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:= _
"1"

Range("F31:F401").Select
Selection.Copy



Sheets(2).Activate


'this is for the raw data to be copied into each worksheet

FirstCell = "D19"
Range(FirstCell).Select
Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""
If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then
Exit Do
Else
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
End If
Loop


Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
False, Transpose:=True

Sheets(3).Activate
FirstCell = "C19"
Range(FirstCell).Select
Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""
If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then
Exit Do
Else
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
End If
Loop
ActiveCell = datepart(ret)

ws.Activate

Range("D31:D401").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy


Sheets(3).Activate
FirstCell = "D19"
Range(FirstCell).Select
Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""
If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then
Exit Do
Else
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
End If
Loop


Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
False, Transpose:=True

Sheets(4).Activate
FirstCell = "C19"
Range(FirstCell).Select
Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""
If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then
Exit Do
Else
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
End If
Loop
ActiveCell = datepart(ret)

ws.Activate

Range("G31:G401").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy



Sheets(4).Activate
FirstCell = "D19"
Range(FirstCell).Select
Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""
If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then
Exit Do
Else
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
End If
Loop


Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
False, Transpose:=True

With ActiveWorkbook
.Worksheets(.Worksheets.Count).Delete
End With
End Sub
Function datepart(filename As Variant) As Date
Dim i As Long
Dim s As String
For i = 1 To Len(filename)
If Mid(filename, i, 8) Like "########" Then
s = Mid(filename, i, 8)
datepart = DateSerial(Right(s, 4), Mid(s, 3, 2), Left(s, 2))
Exit For
End If
Next
End Function
```

Comment: Just tested your code, it do pop out a msgbox then exit sub. You can set a break point to see what's going on.

Comment: I see there is lot of code after exit sub. That will never executed . right?

Comment: Yes, if I were to cancel the process myself it will state that I have cancel the process. But if i were to actually press a file for input, it will still show that i canceled the process and exit sub. You get me ? haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the "End if" that is after your long With Block to be right after the "Exit Sub" like this

```
Dim ret As Variant
'this whole part is for importing the raw data files into excel
ret = Application.GetOpenFilename("Lkl Files (*.lkl), *.lkl")
If ret <> False Then
Else
MsgBox "You've canceled the process"
With ActiveWorkbook
.Worksheets(.Worksheets.Count).Delete
End With
Exit Sub
'**********
'Add this here
'**********
End if

With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
"TEXT;" & ret, Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
.Name = ret
.FieldNames = True
.RowNumbers = False
.FillAdjacentFormulas = False
.PreserveFormatting = True
.RefreshOnFileOpen = False
.RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
.SavePassword = False
.SaveData = True
.AdjustColumnWidth = True
.RefreshPeriod = 0
.TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
.TextFilePlatform = 65001
.TextFileStartRow = 1
.TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
.TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
.TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
.TextFileTabDelimiter = True
.TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
.TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
.TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
.TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
.TextFileDecimalSeparator = ","
.TextFileThousandsSeparator = "."
.TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

End With
'**********
'Remove this one
'**********
'End If
```

Comment: Tried shifting it up but still dont do what i want... No problem with the end if, just that when i select an input file, it still say that i canceled the process and exit sub. Which means, everything after the exit sub, won't be process whether i select and input or not..

Comment: Have you tried putting a Breakpoint on the line with "If ret <> False Then"? You could then run your macro and hover the mouse over "ret" to see what value get passed on to your variable.

Comment: I'm not sure of what you mean. What I'm asking is what is the value for ret you get while the line is highlighted in yellow.

Comment: sorry about just now, you were correct about the end if, i just missed out on the "else" after the "If ret <> False Then"... thank you very much

Comment: now that it can run, i still get i'm missing the end if thing in breakpoint.. but the code works perfectly fine..

Comment: Careful, I think you are mixing up 2 different things. When you get an error message that pops up, that's a run-time error message. It is not the same thing as a Breakpoint ([link](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/4/8/debugging-vba-code-adding-breakpoints))

Comment: owh no wonder.. i was using immediate all along.. i thought they were the same.. really sorry, i'm just 2 weeks old in vba and still learning. appreciate the help and guidance

Answer (score 1):

Missing the ***End If*** after this:

```
If ret <> False Then
Else
MsgBox "You've canceled the process"
With ActiveWorkbook
.Worksheets(.Worksheets.Count).Delete
End With
Exit Sub
```

Comment: There is an End If after With block.

Comment: @newacc2240  not good enough..... ***With ActiveSheet.QueryTables*** can't possibly be executed.